# Run-Time error '1004 - AutoFilter method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am getting the above error when running the below code. I am very new to VBA and need some assistance in debugging.

```
Sub TransferTest1()

Dim INQUIRE As Worksheet
Dim QUOTE As Worksheet
Dim ORDER As Worksheet
Dim YString As String
Dim RecString As String

Set INQUIRE = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inquiries")
Set QUOTE = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes")
Set ORDER = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")

With INQUIRE.Range("A6:K1200")
    .AutoFilter 11, "Y"
    .Offset(1).Resize(, 7).Copy QUOTE.Range("A6")  ' columns A:G
    .AutoFilter
End With

With QUOTE.Range("A6:N1200")
    .AutoFilter 14, "Rec'vd"
    .Offset(1).Resize(, 7).Copy ORDER.Range("A6") ' columns A:G
    .Offset(1).Resize(, 2).Offset(11).Copy ORDER.Range("K6")  ' columns L:M
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

R. Smithey

Comment: Are you sure that your range exactly matches the area you want to filter?

Comment: I have date in range A6 to G6 and then the column "K" which should be the column the .Autofilter 11 refers to in the first with bloc and column  "N" for .AutoFilter 14.

Comment: try only this line (sub or immediate window) and tell us what happens (and if auto filler is enabled in your sheet): `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inquiries").Range("A6:K1200").AutoFilter`

Comment: I have turned off auto filler in the options menu and removed all filters on all 3 sheets. I added in the above code right below Sub TransferTest1 (). The same Run Time Error popped up and then highlights the line of code you wrote above yellow as the error.

Answer (score 1):

Precede each call to `.AutoFilter` with,

```
if .parent.autofiltermode then .parent.autofiltermode = false
```

This will turn off any pre-existing .AutoFilters if they exist and do nothing if they do not exist.

Comment: Would this line of code go on the line above each .AutoFilter command? SO in this case, it would be in my macro 4 times?